# Locate user location on google map using IP address

Tags: php, google-maps, geolocation, ip-address

I want to locate user location on google map. i don't have user lat and long. Is it possible to find out the location through IP address with PHP ???

Comment: Not the exact location based off IP. The best you could do is the general area. You might want to try something first.

Comment: I know its not possible to locate exact area coz every one dont have real IP. But is it possible with php for real IPs ?

Comment: No, it's not possible to locate the exact area based off IP unless it's registered to an organisation.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Geoplugin for php which helps to pin point client's location.
Following syntax may work.

```
<php
echo var_export(unserialize(file_get_contents('http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?ip='.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])));
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/geolocation), they don't recommend using Geolocation because a user's IP address can only provide a rough estimate of a user's location.

> The [W3C approach](https://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html) is the easiest and most fully-supported so it should be prioritized over other methods.

I also found this [example](http://www.rogerethomas.com/blog/php-map-a-users-ip-address-with-google-maps) which might help.

Comment: Not working, get the error  simplexml_load_file(http://api.ipinfodb.com/v2/ip_query.php?key=e43f473aa446e659a1d2